# jquery doesn't work, can't find the right answer here

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

My html code with the jquery link

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>

        <!-- metadata -->
        <meta charset="UTF-8">

        <meta name="keywords" content="bas webdesign, beverwijk, heemskerk, uitgeest, ijmuiden, velsen, noord holland, noord-holland, nederland, responsive webdesign, website bouwen, goedkoop, kwaliteit, betrouwbaar, html 5, css 3, javascript, huisstijl, huisstijlen">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width user-scalable=no">

            <!-- socialmedia -->
            <meta property="og:site_name" content="www.bas-webdesign.nl"/>
            <meta property="og:title" content="Investeer in je bedrijf, investeer in een goede website!"/>
            <meta property="og:description" content="Bas webdesign maakt websites op maat voor elk budget. Jij bepaalt, Bas maakt. Advies is bij Bas een service. En service is gratis, zoals het hoort! Neem gerust contact op en kom eens op de koffie voor een vrijblijvend gesprek."/>
            <meta property="og:image" content="afb/sociaal/socialeMediaThumbnail.jpg">
            <meta property="og:url" content="http://bas-webdesign.nl/">
            <meta property="og:type" content="Webdesign"/>
            <!-- socialmedia -->

        <!-- metadata -->


        <!-- links -->

            <!-- favicon -->
            <link rel="shortcut icon" href="afb/logo/favicon.png" type="image/x-icon">
            <link rel="icon" href="afb/logo/favicon.png" type="image/x-icon">
            <!-- favicon -->

            <!-- fonts -->
            <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Josefin+Sans:400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
            <!-- fonts -->

            <!-- standaard -->
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/reset.css">
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
            <!-- standaard -->

        <!-- links -->


        <!-- script -->

            <!-- jquery -->
            <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
            <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
            <!-- jquery -->

        <script src="js/actions.js"></script>
        <script src="js/smooth-scroll.js"></script> <!-- gebruik "data-scroll" in de a tag voor smoothscroll -->
        <!-- script -->


        <title>Bas Webdesign</title>

    </head>


    <body>

        <!-- omhuller -->
        <div class="omhuller">

            <!-- header -->
            <header id="header">

                <!-- logo -->
                <img src="afb/logo/logo.png">
                <!-- logo -->

                <!-- hoofdmenu -->
                <section id="hoofdmenu">

                    <ul>

                        <li>
                            <span id="menuIcoon_website" class="fa fa-globe" onmouseover="hoverAan(menuIcoon_website, menuTekst_website)"></span>
                            <a href="websites/" id="menuTekst_website" class="onzichtbaar" onmouseout="hoverUit(menuIcoon_website, menuTekst_website)">websites</a>

                        </li>

                        <li>

                        </li>

                        <li>

                        </li>

                        <li>

                        </li>

                    </ul>

                </section>
                <!-- hoofdmenu -->

            </header>
            <!-- header -->

        </div>
        <!-- omhuller -->


        <script>
            smoothScroll.init();
        </script>

    </body>
</html>
```

And here I want to start my hover function.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

// globale variabelen

// globale variabelen


// functies

    // hover

        function hoverAan(onzichtbaar, zichtbaar){

            onzichtbaar.style.display = "none";
            zichtbaar.style.display = "inline";

        }

    // hover

// functies

});
```

The thing is... Without the `jquery link and .ready()` (so plain js) it does work. Is it the position of the jquery link? or is there something else I do wrong? because I want to write a lot of `jquery` instead of `js`. So I wanted to make sure it does the job from the very beginning.. and now it does not.

Comment: Where do you call `hoverAan`? It is not in the code you provided...

Comment: I call it in a link..
<ul>
<li>
<span id="menuIcoon_website" class="fa fa-globe" onmouseover="hoverAan(menuIcoon_website, menuTekst_website)"></span>
</li>
</ul>

Comment: Where is this `ul` in your code? Please provide the entire code so that others can help you out.

Comment: it's updated.. sorry about that ;)

Comment: Form a habit to code in English, since a) the programming language itself is based on english and b) you just found out that people worldwide might look at your code.

Comment: I'll keep it in mind ;)

Answer (score 0):

You want to keep all your JavaScript functions outside of your `$(document).ready(function () {});`. This way, your functions will be loaded in-line with your HTML, instead of your functions being loaded after your HTML is loaded.

Comment: oke, but if I use jquery inside a function outside "$(document).ready(function () {});" it will still work?

Comment: Yes. `$(document).ready(function () {});` will literally wait for the page to be done loading, and only then will everything inside be loaded. See https://api.jquery.com/ready/ for more information. Everything outside of it will be loaded along the page load, like normal JavaScript scripts / functions. Besides that, earlier in the page you're including jQuery so all jQuery functions should work after that inclusion.